# ¿Alguien me puede ayudar con Select2 para la modificación de un combo autocomplete con llamada AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select2

Estoy modificando una página que solo funcionaba en explorer 8, he conseguido que todo se muestre correctamente en IE11 y chrome aunque con algunos estilos con deseo de mejorarlos, el problema es que todo funciona correctamente excepto al pulsar sobre los botones de los combos, EN TODOS! He visto que me redirecciona a su mismo action de la ventana general y a la vez con el del combo (estoy trabajando con struts), quedándose los dos hilos suspendidos y esto hace que la aplicación pete y me aparezca el error que tenemos como mensaje informativo. Tras varios intentos he decidido cambiar el combo puesto que no puedo deshabilitar el submit para ver si así logro corregir este problema.

He descargado Select2, pero tengo gran variedad de archivos y no se exactamente cual debo elegir y como debo retocar o añadir las cosas.

Aquí está el código de uno de los combos:

```
    $.widget("#ui.comboboxE", {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this;
            var select = this.element.hide();
            var input = $("<input size='80' id='cmbE' name='cmbE'>")
                .insertAfter(select)
                .autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "/t/t004_ESelect.do?sSortDir_0=ASC&iSortCol_0=0&cod_e_varios=" + request.term,
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                featureClass: "P",
                                style: "full",
                                maxRows: 12,
                                name_startsWith: request.term
                            },
                            success: function(data) {           
                                response($.map(data.aaData, function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        id: item[0],
                                        label: item[0]+ ' - '+item[2],
                                        value: item[0]+ ' - '+item[2]
                                    }
                                })) 
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    delay: 0,
                    change: function(event, ui) {
                        fnChangeCombo(event, ui, this, '[name="descripcione"]',['[name="cod_e"]']);
                        limpiarL();
                        $('[name="descripcionl"]').val("");
                        $('[name="cod_l"]').val("");
                    },
                    select : function(event, ui) {
                        self._trigger("selected", event, {
                            item: select.find("[value='" + ui.item.id + "']")
                        });
                        $('[name="descripcione"]').val(ui.item.label);
                        $('[name="cod_e"]').val(ui.item.id);
                    },
                    minLength: 0
                })
                .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
                $("<button>&nbsp;</button>")
                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                .insertAfter(input)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
                .click(function() {
                    if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                        input.autocomplete("close");
                        return;
                    }
                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                    input.focus();
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hola Javier GT y bienvenido a SO en Español. ¿Podrías compartir parte del código del que hablas para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Ahí lo tienes, Gracias Miquel Coll

Comment: Vamos mejorando :) ¿Has intentado ejecutar con la consola abierta (f12) a ver qué error te salta?

Comment: jajaja si, lo he intentado prácticamente todo, el modo depuración de los navegadores y el del entorno los tenemos desgastados ya. Por si sirve de ayuda, el código de la aplicación está bastante anticuado, por tiempo no nos hemos puesto a retocarlo (puesto sería empezar de 0) esto lleva a que cualquier tipo de actualización de jQuery o alguna librería suponga una gran variedad de cambios. Para el resto de funciones y estilos no he tenido que tocar muchas cosas, por eso he estado peleando aprox. un mes para intentar arreglar lo de los combos sin tener que cambiar nada (hubiese sido lo mejor).

Comment: Solucionado Miquel Coll, se debía a que por defecto en los nuevos navegadores viene definido el type como submit, por lo que cargaba su página a la cual estaba enlazada con el action abriendo dos hilos y produciendo así el error, tan solo puse el type button y se solucionó, lo extraño es que para aquellos combos que cargan un "subcombo" por la relación con el primero no me funcionan al ponerle a este type button... En fin, a ver que solución encuentro. Gracias de todos modos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Solucionado! (La parte del combo sin usar select2) Al parecer si no especificas el type de button (en mi caso) este por defecto por jQuery aparece como submit (desconozco porque con IE8 sin tampoco especificarlo aparecía como button) era por esto que siempre me redireccionaba a la ventana principal de la opción de menú seleccionada y no cargaba el combo sin más en la misma página en la que me encontraba. Para solucionarlo cambié la siguiente línea de código:

```
     $.widget("#ui.comboboxE", {
    _create: function() {
        var self = this;
        var select = this.element.hide();
        var input = $("<input size='80' id='cmbE' name='cmbE'>")
            .insertAfter(select)
            .autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "/t/t004_ESelect.do?sSortDir_0=ASC&iSortCol_0=0&cod_e_varios=" + request.term,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            featureClass: "P",
                            style: "full",
                            maxRows: 12,
                            name_startsWith: request.term
                        },
                        success: function(data) {           
                            response($.map(data.aaData, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    id: item[0],
                                    label: item[0]+ ' - '+item[2],
                                    value: item[0]+ ' - '+item[2]
                                }
                            })) 
                        }
                    })
                },
                delay: 0,
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    fnChangeCombo(event, ui, this, '[name="descripcione"]',['[name="cod_e"]']);
                    limpiarL();
                    $('[name="descripcionl"]').val("");
                    $('[name="cod_l"]').val("");
                },
                select : function(event, ui) {
                    self._trigger("selected", event, {
                        item: select.find("[value='" + ui.item.id + "']")
                    });
                    $('[name="descripcione"]').val(ui.item.label);
                    $('[name="cod_e"]').val(ui.item.id);
                },
                minLength: 0
            })
            .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
            var botoncombo = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>") /*AQUÍ ESTÁ EL CAMBIO*/
            .attr("tabIndex", -1)
            .insertAfter(input)
            .button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
            })
            .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
            .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
            .click(function() {
                if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                    input.autocomplete("close");
                    return;
                }
                input.autocomplete("search", "");
                input.focus();
            });
        }
    });
```

Como observáis a diferencia del código de la pregunta la única diferencia es la que tiene el comentario en mayúsculas, lo pongo aquí por separado para que lo veáis más fácilmente: Ahora:

```
     var botoncombo = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
```

Antes:

```
    $("<button >&nbsp;</button>")
```